# why do parseInt and isNaN in JavaScript have inconsistent behavior?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node.js with v8.11.3.

`parseInt("")` returns `NaN`, but `isNaN("")` returns `false`:

```js
console.log(
  parseInt(''),
  isNaN('')
);
```

another example:

```js
console.log(
  parseFloat('0x5'),
  parseInt('0x5')
);
```

Comment: You think this is the only thing "wrong" with Javascript? lulz. You should probably browse https://7chan.org/pr/src/OReilly_JavaScript_The_Good_Parts_May_2008.pdf

Comment: @vicatcu but the document you give mainly focuses on the good parts of Javascript. So you think this is not inconsistent, it has its special consideration?

Answer (score 4):

Per MDN docs, [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt returns NaN.

There is no first character in the empty string - it cannot be converted to a number, so `NaN` is returned.

But [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) is different. As the first paragraph of MDN says:

> Note: coercion inside the isNaN function has interesting rules; you may alternatively want to use Number.isNaN(), as defined in ECMAScript 2015.

...

> When the argument to the isNaN function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number.

The empty string, when coerced to a Number, is 0:

```js
const result = Number('');
console.log(result + ' : ' + typeof result);
```

You might try using `parseInt` and *then* checking to see if the result is `NaN` or not:

```js
const possibleInt = parseInt('');
console.log(Number.isNaN(possibleInt));
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of Number() just shuffles the problem around. For example:

```
parseInt("14px"); // 14
parseInt("abc"); // NaN
parseInt(""); // NaN (i.e. null string is a number)
```

versus use of isNaN:

```
isNaN("14px"); // false
isNaN("abc"); // true
isNaN(""); // false
```

versus use of Number():

```
Number("14px"); // NaN
Number("abc"); // NaN
Number(""); // 0
```

And, making it more complicated, you can't even do:

```
parseInt(x) == NaN ? 0 : parseInt(x);
```

because comparisons with NaN are always false, even NaN == NaN is false.

The simplest that I found was:

```
x=="" || !isNaN(x) ? 0 : parseInt(x);
```

but this assumes that the null string is the only anomaly, so it may not work in all cases.